# Can't get List to display inline?

Tags: css, html

I would prefer to keep the css for the list inline.  Not in a separate CSS.  Is it the way my id's are stacked?  Any other comments would be greatly appreciated as well.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My First Site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="container"><!--entire body-->

    <div id="topbar"><!--css uses a #-->

    <div class="fixedwidth"><!--.fixedwidth in css-->

    <div id="logodiv">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="site logo">
    </div><!--logodiv-->


    <div id="topMenuDiv"><!-- should this be the div id?  or should it be in the ul?-->

    <ul style="list-style-type:none"; 
    display:inline;>

    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    </div><!--topmenudiv"-->

    </div><!--topbar-->
    </div><!--fixedwidth-->

    </div><!--container-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You could keep the CSS in the same file but put it in a `<style>` tag in your `<head>` to clean up your HTML a bit.

Answer (score 1):

`<ul style="list-style-type:none; display:inline;">` just simple typo error.

Comment: if it solved your problem, plaase choose as accepted answer so other users can get it as helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You have syntax error here :**

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none"; 
display:inline;>
```

**It should be like this :**

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none; display:inline;">
```

**CSS :**

```
ul, ul li { list-style-type;none; display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasted two hours trying to figure it out.